# How can I get the markers that are within the circle radius?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a map that already contains markers. I will like to be able to specific a circle radius around a specified location and select all markers that resides within.

The code to added the Circle is done. I need to know how to get the markers.

Can anyone help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the markers in an array then you can calculate the distance from each of marker to the center of your circle using the [computeDistanceBetween function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical), and add to a second array only those whose `distance <= radius`.